# Regex Python Retirar tudo o que vem antes da primeira letra em uma string

Tags: python, regex

Outra dúvida de REGEX que nenhuma das respostas que eu encontrei segue.
Eu tenho um dataframe que algumas strings começam erroneamente com coisas que não são Letras, por exemplo :

`t = ['. Subordinam-se ao regime',  '1º O acesso à informação']`

O resultado que eu quero é

`'Subordinam-se ao regime',  'O acesso à informação'`

Eu estou tentando `re.sub(r'[[:alpha:]]+', '', t)` sem sucesso, o que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu exemplo, `t` é uma lista, então não adianta passá-la diretamente para `re.sub`. Você tem que passar uma string de cada vez.

Sendo assim, uma opção é usar:

```
import re

t = ['. Subordinam-se ao regime',  '1º O acesso à informação']
for s in t:
    print(re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z]+', '', s))
```

A regex usa o marcador `^` que indica o início da string. Depois temos `[^a-zA-Z]+` (uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere que **não** seja uma letra).

Ou seja, substituímos qualquer coisa que não seja letra e esteja no início da string. A saída será:

```
Subordinam-se ao regime
O acesso à informação
```

---

Se tiver letras acentuadas, pode trocar para:

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

t = ['. Subordinam-se ao regime',  '1º O acesso à informação', ' - É blabla etc']
for s in t:
    print(re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z]+', '', normalize('NFD', s)))
```

Eu uso `normalize` para converter a string para NFD. Para entender o que é a normalização, leia [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052), mas basicamente letras como `É` são decompostas em duas: a letra `E` sem acento e o próprio acento. Assim, passamos a considerar também caracteres acentuados.

---

O problema é que ao normalizar você muda o conteúdo original.

Claro que outra alternativa é incluir todos os caracteres acentuados na regex, algo como:

```
re.sub('^[^a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+', '', s)
```

Só coloquei as letras com acento agudo, mas aí basta adicionar as demais dentro dos colchetes.

---

E também pode ser feito sem regex:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

# retorna a string a partir da primeira letra
def apos_primeira_letra(s):
    # coloque aqui todas as letras válidas
    letras_validas = ascii_lowercase + 'çáéíóúãõâô'
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c.lower() in letras_validas:
            return s[i:] # retorna da letra em diante
    return s # se não encontrou nenhuma letra, retorna a própria string

t = ['. Subordinam-se ao regime',  '1º O acesso à informação', ' - É blabla etc']
for s in t:
    print(apos_primeira_letra(s))
```

A ideia é ter todas as letras válidas em `letras_validas` (coloquei só as minúsculas para facilitar, assim na hora de verificar você usa `lower()` para cada caractere sendo verificado).

Inicialmente eu tinha pensado em usar `isalpha()` para verificar se é letra, mas este método retorna `True` para o caractere `º`, então achei melhor fixar as letras que vou considerar válidas.

Assim, a função `apos_primeira_letra` percorre a string, e se encontrar uma letra, retorna tudo dali pra frente. Se não encontrar nenhuma, retorna a mesma string sem modificação.

Comment: Segunda regex que você me fornece hoje @hkotsubo ! Muito obrigada, funcionou!

Comment: Vale citar aqui que a expressão não considerará corretamente os caracteres acentuados. Por exemplo, uma frase como "É claro que funciona" ficaria "claro que funciona". Talvez isso possa gerar efeitos colaterais e é um cuidado que a autora da pergunta deva ter.

Comment: @Woss Calma que estou atualizando a resposta :-)

Comment: Estou calmo, poxa xD

Comment: @Woss Pronto, agora sim :-)

Comment: Aí entra também em casos como os caracteres a serem removidos façam parte do conteúdo, tipo como "-5°C era a temperatura naquele momento" - sei que você, Hugo, sabe, mas comentando apenas para a Jéssica tomar todos os cuidados quando se usa REGEX.